# Passing get variables to index page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, controller, get

I am creating a social networking web application using codeigniter. The web application has features similar to facebook pages. I need to accomplish something which seems to be impossible. Since codeigniter recognizes controllers and functions based on the URL order, I am unable to directly pass an argument to the controller index function. I am trying to access a page as "www.mywebsite.com/page/CodeIgniter" where 'CodeIgniter' will be the page name which the 'page' controller will accept it as an argument and accordingly parse the page. Since codeigniter parses url as "www.mywebsite.com/{controller}/{function}", I am unable to link to a page as how we do in facebook. Could anyone help me out on how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Using [routes](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) should solve this issue;

**config/routes.php**

```
$route['page/(\w+)'] = 'page/index/$1';
```

This example is simple, but do note that it will "hijack" most other calls which have only 2 segments.

If you got a few values which you will pass, do consider something such as:

```
$route['page/(CodeIgniter|Drupal|Joomla)'] = 'page/index/$1';
```

Or a preffix:

```
$route['page/cms_(\w+)'] = 'page/index/$1';
```

And have the url `domain.com/page/cms_CodeIgniter` instead.